# Burning smell in my clothes dryer

Tags: dryer, smell

There is a burning smell inside my clothes dryer  after it runs. Does anyone know what that could be? There is no smoke (thankfully) but it definitely has a mild to medium smell or something burning. I think its a gas powered dryer (its hard to get to the back too look) but the smell is closer to burning lint than to gas.

My first response was to clean out the area under the lint collection basket. We clean the collection basket before each use but the area under that had collected a fair amount of lint and so I cleaned it after we first smelled the smoke. I also checked the exhaust hose that connects to the wall but there was no lint in there. I then ran the dryer again after this cleaning and it still smells of smoke. Is there another place to clean? Do I just have to let it run some to let it air out? Or, is there something else I should do?

I am fairly handy myself but don't have any experience with troubleshooting dryers. Is this something I could probably remedy myself or is it something more serious that requires me to call a repair person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it smells like burning lint, it's probably burning lint.  If the seals are worn around the lint trap (as evidenced by the amount collected underneath), the interior of the dryer can accumulate lint really fast.  I'd remove the case and vacuum and or blow out the lint that has collected there.

This would also be a perfect time to give your dryer vent a good cleaning.  If it's clogged or severely constricted, this can also cause lint to back up into the dryer chassis.

Either of these situations can be a pretty serious fire hazard, and given that you're already smelling burning, I wouldn't use the dryer until you've done *both* of these.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with my electric GE dryer. The plate on the inside had trapped lint that was turning brown and causing the burning smell which smelled like sulfur or burning rubber depending who you talked to. It required unscrewing 3 torx bolts and removing the back plate on the inside of the dryer. I then cleaned out the lint with a vacuum and some wet wipes. I laid the dryer on it's back and put the 3 screws in and voila! Done. 5 minutes of work no more burning smell. Other manufacturers require taking apart the back to access the lint behind the plate. I hope that this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a burning smell inside my clothes dryer after it runs. Does anyone know what that could be?

Yes.  Burning smells are a common indicator that something is burning.  So something is burning.

> There is no smoke (thankfully) but it definitely has a mild to medium smell or something burning. I think its a gas powered dryer (its hard to get to the back too look) but the smell is closer to burning lint than to gas.

Getting to the back to look is going to be easier for you than anyone on the internet.  Use a chair to stand on and take a peek.  Bring a flashlight with you in case there is not ambient light behind the dryer.  Do not drop the flashlight behind the dryer, or fall off the chair.

You could also try shutting off the gas to your house and see if the dryer still works.

> Do I just have to let it run some to let it air out? Or, is there something else I should do?

Configure its controls NOT to provide heat, and then run it for a few hours with heat off, in an attempt to move enough air through it to clear smells.  Have a fire extinguisher ready.

> I am fairly handy myself but don't have any experience with troubleshooting dryers. Is this something I could probably remedy myself or is it something more serious that requires me to call a repair person?

Open the dryer up (remove the outer casing and look inside).  Use visual sensing to identify the area or areas that are chared, and replace them with OEM parts from the manufacturer.

Comment: I marked the other answer as correct even though yours was technically correct because that answer was not as condescending as your answer.

Comment: Gee willikers!  I hope that makes you feel warm inside.  You'll need it this winter, after this dryer burns your house down.

Comment: You aren't really helping your case...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check if you have any cracks on the blower wheel. This could also cause a burning smell on your dryer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lint fire in a gas dryer is more likely than in an electric model.  Accumulated lint close to an open flame is not good!  Disassembly to access the floor, gas valve assembly and chimney is required for cleaning.  YT videos are available to help. 1/4" and 5/16" magnetic nut drivers make the job easier!

Comment: directing someone to do more searching isn't really the quality we expect in an answer around here.